# Dask Tutorial: Explain unexpected results from tutorial

Tags: dask

The tutorial page requested that we ask questions here.

On tutorial `01_dask.delayed`, there is the following code:

### Parallelizing Increment

#### Prep

```py
from time import sleep

def inc(x):
    sleep(1)
    return x + 1

def add(x, y):
    sleep(1)
    return x + y

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

#### Calc

```py
results = []

for x in data:
    y = delayed(inc)(x)
    results.append(y)
    
total = delayed(sum)(results)
print("Before computing:", total)  # Let's see what type of thing total is
result = total.compute()
print("After computing :", result)  # After it's computed
```

This code takes 1 second.  This makes sense; each of the 8 `inc` calculations takes 1 second, the rest are ~ instantaneous, and it can all be run fully in parallel.

### Parallelizing Increment and Double

#### Prep

```py
def double(x):
    sleep(1)
    return 2 * x

def is_even(x):
    return not x % 2

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

#### Calc

```py
results = []
for x in data:
    if is_even(x):  # even
        y = delayed(double)(x)
    else:          # odd
        y = delayed(inc)(x)
    results.append(y)
    
#total = delayed(sum)(results)
total = sum(results)
```

This takes **2 seconds**, which seems strange to me.  The situation is the same as above; there are 10 actions that each take 1 second each, and can again be run fully in parallel.

The only thing I can imagine is that my machine is only able to allow for 8 tasks in parallel, but this is tough to know for sure because I have an [Intel Core i7](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/processors/core/i7-processors.html) and it seems that some have 8 threads and some have 16.  (I have a [MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP756?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US), and Apple notoriously likes to hide this detailed information from us pleebs.)

Can anyone confirm if this is what is going on?  I am nearly certain, because bumping the `data` object for the first portion from `data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` to `data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` also bumps the time up to 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your analysis is correct, and you have 8 threads running in parallel for 1s each, before moving on to the remaining data, which do not fill all the threads, but still take 1s to complete.

You may want to try with the distributed scheduler, which provides dashboards for more feedback on what is going on (see later in the tutorial).